Swift tasks dependency handling
I have 2 async tasks. And one task runs in a nested manner based on condition from other task. I want to achieve something like the code below.
Both Task1 and Task2 have AsyncStreams returning multiple values in a stream. Based on these values, I start Task2.
Any suggestions please ?
Task1 {
  /// AsyncStream1
  for try await result1 in stream1 {
    if result1 == A {
      Task2 {
        /// AsyncStream2
        for try await result2 in stream2 {
          if result2 == X {
            /// Stop Task2 if Task1 has completed (Stream1 has finished)
            /// THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if result1 == B {
      /// Stop Task1 if Task2 has completed (Stream2 has finished)
      /// THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
    }
  }
}

Only one Task2 will be created. Usecase is such that result1 == A will be received max once and hance only one Task2. Assume if case reaches result1 == B, Task2 would have begun already.

Only one Task2 will be created. Usecase is such that result1 == A will be received max once and hance only one Task2.
Assume if case reaches result1 == B, task2 would have begun already.

There is a slight difference between "stream1 finishes" and "the for await loop that consumes stream1 finishes". It is possible for a stream to yield all its elements before a for await loop can consume all of them. Which one do you mean?

I meant the for await loop that consumes stream1 finishes, because thats when we know all data sent by stream has been processed.

You can just set a flag to true at the end of the for await loops. Isolate the flags to an actor in order to do this safely.
Assuming that the tasks will not be cancelled,
actor SomeActor {
    var task1Finished = false
    var task2Finished = false
    
    func startTask1() async throws {
        for try await result1 in stream1 {
            if result1 == A {
                Task {
                    try await startTask2()
                }
            }
            if result1 == B, task2Finished {
                break
            }
        }
        task1Finished = true
    }
    
    func startTask2() async throws {
        for try await result2 in stream2 {
            if result2 == X, task1Finished {
                break
            }
        }
        task2Finished = true
    }
}

If you need to handle cancelation, check Task.isCancelled in the loop and set the flags appropriately.

Rather than if statement inside the loop, I would just cancel the other asynchronous sequence at the end of the respective for await loop (which, by definition, is when the sequence is done):
actor Example {
    var task1: Task<Void, Error>?
    var task2: Task<Void, Error>?
    
    func startTask1() {
        task1 = Task {
            for try await result1 in stream1 {
                …
            }

            task2?.cancel()                    // when stream1 finishes, cancel task2/stream2
        }
    }
    
    func startTask2() {
        task2 = Task {
            for try await result2 in stream2 {
                …
            }

            task1?.cancel()                    // when stream2 finishes, cancel task1/stream1
        }
    }
}

This approach lends itself naturally to support cancelation (see below).

Here is a MRE. I’ve expanded upon the above example, with:

Change startTask1 to be an async method that supports cancelation;
Rather than canceling at the end of the for await loop, I use defer statements so that we catch any “early exits” … this is a slightly more robust way of making sure you can’t accidentally overlook some path of execution;
In the absence of definitions for stream1/stream2, I made up some asynchronous sequences for demonstration purposes (the exact nature of the sequences doesn’t matter, but I just needed something); and
I have attempted to add if statements akin to the ones in your example.

Thus:
actor Example {
    let A = 2
    let B = 4
    let X = "four"

    var task1: Task<Void, Error>?
    var task2: Task<Void, Error>?
    
    func startTask1() async throws {
        assert(task1 == nil)
        
        let task = Task {
            defer { task2?.cancel() }          // this will cancel task2 when this task exits (i.e., when stream1 finishes)
            
            let stream1 = sequence1()
            
            // loop through stream1
            for try await result1 in stream1 {
                print("result1:", result1)

                if result1 == A {
                    startTask2()
                } else if result1 == B {
                    break                      // exit the `for await` loop, thereby ending this sequence
                }
            }
        }
        task1 = task
        
        try await withTaskCancellationHandler { 
            _ = try await task.value
        } onCancel: { 
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    func startTask2() {
        task2 = Task {
            defer { task1?.cancel() }          // this will cancel task1 when this task exits (i.e., when stream2 finishes)
            
            let stream2 = sequence2(interval: .milliseconds(400))
            
            for try await result2 in stream2 {
                print("result2:", result2)
                
                if result2 == X { 
                    break                      // exit the `for await` loop, thereby ending this sequence
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sequence1(interval: Duration = .seconds(1)) -> AsyncStream<Int> {
        .init { continuation in
            let task = Task {
                for i in 0 ..< 10 {
                    continuation.yield(i)
                    try? await Task.sleep(for: interval)
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
            continuation.onTermination = { state in
                if case .cancelled = state {
                    task.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sequence2(interval: Duration = .seconds(1)) -> AsyncStream<String> {
        .init { continuation in
            let task = Task {
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
                
                for i in 0 ..< 10 {
                    continuation.yield(formatter.string(for: i)!)
                    try? await Task.sleep(for: interval)
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
            
            continuation.onTermination = { state in
                if case .cancelled = state {
                    task.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I wouldn’t get too lost in the details here, but focus on the big picture idea, to just cancel the Task associated with the other AsyncSequence if the for await loop exits.
